# CloudFlare - Multiple requests to origin server during the max-age period

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I'm new to CloudFlare and I want to server images through them. (adserver).
Looking at my nginx access logs I'm getting multiple requests per hour.

But in the page-rules I've put:

[image]

and doing curl -svo /dev/null https://.... I get the right answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting CloudFlare to serve and cache images, there's an easier way than using page rules.

By default, CloudFlare will cache [static content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content), which includes images, CSS and JS files.

Knowing this, go to **dashboard > domain > caching**

The **caching level** will probably be standard, but read the details from the help dropdown.

Set the **browser cache expiration** to 1 month and then you are done.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: that's all you need then ;) Sorry, it wasn't clear to me that you already had this in place.

Comment: what I should have said is that it wasn't clear to me that you had enabled caching in dashboard > domain > caching.  You have a limited number of page rules, so in general you are better off keeping page rules for other tasks.

Comment: thanks. It's still the same now, but it doesn't matter as I added 2 levels of cache before cloudflare.